# Encrypting message gives error : throw new TypeError('unexpected type ' + t + ', use Uint8Array');

Tags: ed25519

```
var nacl1 = require('ed2curve');
var nacl = require('tweetnacl');
nacl.util = require('tweetnacl-util');

const theirPublicKey = nacl1.convertSecretKey("GDGM7ZAV5OJIVD375PBOJCBM2FDJOQKDJ5GCNKIGGMX7USFIHNQY2BTT");
console.log(theirPublicKey)

const mySecretKey = nacl1.convertSecretKey("SC77LFF57OC47LBV4D7WZ73FSQ67CL4JPVK65HOZJYCCPTO4IUMECFFJ");

console.log(mySecretKey)
var message = nacl.util.decodeUTF8('Hello!')
console.log(message)

var encryptedMessage = nacl.box(message, theirPublicKey, mySecretKey);
```

throw new TypeError('unexpected type ' + t + ', use Uint8Array');
       ^

TypeError: unexpected type [object Undefined], use Uint8Array
    at checkArrayTypes (/home/priya/go_test/src/github.com/ed25519/node_modules/tweetnacl/nacl-fast.js:2152:14)
    at Function.nacl.box.before (/home/priya/go_test/src/github.com/ed25519/node_modules/tweetnacl/nacl-fast.js:2225:3)
    at Object.nacl.box (/home/priya/go_test/src/github.com/ed25519/node_modules/tweetnacl/nacl-fast.js:2220:20)
    at Object. (/home/priya/go_test/src/github.com/ed25519/curve.js:14:29)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)

This what I am getting. So please help me to resolve this. Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you generate `Keypair` using `ed25519` you need to use stellar sdk to convert keys in string representation.

See exact StrKey functions function below of Stellar SDk:

```
/**
     * StrKey is a helper class that allows encoding and decoding strkey.
     */

    var StrKey = exports.StrKey = (function () {
      function StrKey() {
        _classCallCheck(this, StrKey);
      }

      _createClass(StrKey, null, {
        encodeEd25519PublicKey: {
          /**
           * Encodes data to strkey ed25519 public key.
           * @param {Buffer} data data to encode
           * @returns {string}
           */

          value: function encodeEd25519PublicKey(data) {
            return encodeCheck("ed25519PublicKey", data);
          }
        },
        decodeEd25519PublicKey: {

          /**
           * Decodes strkey ed25519 public key to raw data.
           * @param {string} data data to decode
           * @returns {Buffer}
           */

          value: function decodeEd25519PublicKey(data) {
            return decodeCheck("ed25519PublicKey", data);
          }
        },
        isValidEd25519PublicKey: {

          /**
           * Returns true if the given Stellar public key is a valid ed25519 public key.
           * @param {string} publicKey public key to check
           * @returns {boolean}
           */

          value: function isValidEd25519PublicKey(publicKey) {
            return isValid("ed25519PublicKey", publicKey);
          }
        },
        encodeEd25519SecretSeed: {

          /**
           * Encodes data to strkey ed25519 seed.
           * @param {Buffer} data data to encode
           * @returns {string}
           */

          value: function encodeEd25519SecretSeed(data) {
            return encodeCheck("ed25519SecretSeed", data);
          }
        },
        decodeEd25519SecretSeed: {

          /**
           * Decodes strkey ed25519 seed to raw data.
           * @param {string} data data to decode
           * @returns {Buffer}
           */

          value: function decodeEd25519SecretSeed(data) {
            return decodeCheck("ed25519SecretSeed", data);
          }
        },
        isValidEd25519SecretSeed: {

          /**
           * Returns true if the given Stellar secret key is a valid ed25519 secret seed.
           * @param {string} seed seed to check
           * @returns {boolean}
           */

          value: function isValidEd25519SecretSeed(seed) {
            return isValid("ed25519SecretSeed", seed);
          }
        },
        encodePreAuthTx: {

          /**
           * Encodes data to strkey preAuthTx.
           * @param {Buffer} data data to encode
           * @returns {string}
           */

          value: function encodePreAuthTx(data) {
            return encodeCheck("preAuthTx", data);
          }
        },
        decodePreAuthTx: {

          /**
           * Decodes strkey PreAuthTx to raw data.
           * @param {string} data data to decode
           * @returns {Buffer}
           */

          value: function decodePreAuthTx(data) {
            return decodeCheck("preAuthTx", data);
          }
        },
        encodeSha256Hash: {

          /**
           * Encodes data to strkey sha256 hash.
           * @param {Buffer} data data to encode
           * @returns {string}
           */

          value: function encodeSha256Hash(data) {
            return encodeCheck("sha256Hash", data);
          }
        },
        decodeSha256Hash: {

          /**
           * Decodes strkey sha256 hash to raw data.
           * @param {string} data data to decode
           * @returns {Buffer}
           */

          value: function decodeSha256Hash(data) {
            return decodeCheck("sha256Hash", data);
          }
        }
      });

      return StrKey;
    })();
```

Answer (score 1):

TweetNacl doesn't talk Stellar. You need to convert the keys from their StrKey representation to Buffers.

StellarSdk.StrKey.decodeEd25519PublicKey() and
StellarSdk.StrKey.decodeEd25519SecretSeed() is a good start, for javascript.